# Create static array with variadic templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

There was an answer on stackoverflow (which I can't seem to find anymore) which demonstrated how a variadic template can be used in C++11 to create a static array at compile time:

```
template <class T, T... args> 
struct array_
{
    static const T data[sizeof...(args)];
};

template <class T, T... args> 
const T array_<T, args...>::data[sizeof...(args)] = { args... };
```

A recursive meta-function could be provided to instantiate `array_` with any number of parameters, which will then be copied at compile time into the internal array.  It's a useful way to create meta-functions for generating constant arrays at compile time.

However, one problem is that it depends on *class template parameters* to get the actual values to populate the array.  This results in one major limitation: only integral constants can be used as value template parameters.  So, you can't use this technique to generate arrays of custom types.

I tried to think of something to work around this limitation, but can't come up with anything.  Is there any way to make this technique work with non-integral constants?

Comment: A std::string is likely to have a dynamic memory allocation internally. How would you do that at compile time? :-)

Comment: @Bo, yes an std::string was a bad example.  But what about a custom POD struct?

Comment: I believe this is the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2981617/1053968) referred to in the question.

Comment: Look at my question, there is a good answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/20388055/293195

Comment: @BoPersson it's impossible to create compile-time string, but it's possible to create compile-time c-string and convert it to string in runtime (or, if using c++17, to string_view in compile-time too). [Here](https://pastebin.com/fQ7GBxCi) you can find an example useage of this technique along with some related meta-functions.

Answer (score 7):

Well, you can indeed populate a static array with custom types (i.e. classes) instances provided that they are constructable from integer types (or whatever other types one may provide as non template parameters and which I am not going enumerate here).

Just take look at the example bellow, which I believe is clear enough to be self explaining:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class my_class
{
    public:
        my_class(T)
        {
            //construct
        }

        void print_something()
        {
            std::cout << "something\n";
        }
};

template<class C, class T, T ... args>
struct array_
{
        static C data[sizeof...(args)];
};

template<class C, class T, T ... args>
C array_<C, T, args...>::data[sizeof...(args)] = {C(args)...};

int main()
{
    array_<my_class<int> , int, 1, 200, 0, 42>::data[2].print_something();
}
```

Note: compiled just fine under GCC 4.6

Answer (score 2):

In C++11 (and especially in C++14), the best way to initialize objects at compile-time is with `constexpr` constructors, not by playing metagames with the typesystem.

```
struct MyObject {
    int x_, y_;
    constexpr MyObject(int x, int y) : x_(x), y_(y) { }
};

const MyObject array[] = { MyObject(1,2), MyObject(3,4) };
```

You can apply your "generator function" idea here, too, if you really want to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#if __cplusplus < 201400
template<size_t... II> struct integer_sequence { typedef integer_sequence type; };
template<size_t N, size_t... II> struct make_index_sequence;
template<size_t... II> struct make_index_sequence<0, II...> : integer_sequence<II...> {};
template<size_t N, size_t... II> struct make_index_sequence : make_index_sequence<N-1, N-1, II...> {};
#define HACK(x) typename x::type
#else
#include <utility>  // the C++14 way of doing things
using std::integer_sequence;
using std::make_index_sequence;
#define HACK(x) x
#endif


struct MyObject {
    int x_, y_;
    constexpr MyObject(int x, int y) : x_(x), y_(y) { }
};

template<typename T, int N, T (*Func)(int), typename Indices>
struct GeneratedArrayHelper;

template<typename T, int N, T (*Func)(int), size_t... i>
struct GeneratedArrayHelper<T, N, Func, integer_sequence<i...>> {
    static const T data[N];  // element i is initialized with Func(i)
};

template<typename T, int N, T (*Func)(int), size_t... i>
const T GeneratedArrayHelper<T,N,Func, integer_sequence<i...>>::data[N] =
    { Func(i)... };

template<typename T, int N, T (*Func)(int)>
struct GeneratedArray :
    GeneratedArrayHelper<T, N, Func, HACK(make_index_sequence<N>)> {};

constexpr MyObject newObject(int i) { return MyObject(2*i, 2*i+1); }

int main() {
    for (const MyObject& m : GeneratedArray<MyObject, 5, newObject>::data) {
        printf("%d %d\n", m.x_, m.y_);
    }

    // Output:
    //   0 1
    //   2 3
    //   4 5
    //   6 7
    //   8 9
}
```

I don't know why Clang 3.5 and GCC 4.8 insist that I put the `HACK()` macro in there, but they refuse to compile the code without it. Probably I made some dumb mistake and someone can point it out. Also, I'm not confident that all the `const`s and `constexpr`s are in the best places.

Comment: There is one good reason to play metaprogramming games: if you want to ensure you only have a single instance for each expression. You could use a hash table or something, but that is unneeded if you do the template foo.

Answer (score 1):

Non-type template arguments can also be pointers or references, provided they point or refer to an object with external linkage.

```
template<typename T, T& t>
struct ref {
    static T&
    get() { return t; }
};

int i = 0;
int& ri = ref<int, i>::get(); // ok

static int j = 0;
int& rj = ref<int, j>::get(); // not ok

const int jj = 0; // here, const implies internal linkage; whoops
const int& rjj = ref<const int, jj>::get(); // not ok

extern const int k = 0;
const int& rk = ref<const int, k>::get(); // ok

namespace {
int l = 0;
}
int& rl = ref<int, l>::get(); // ok, and l is specific to the TU
```

I don't think you'd really want to init the elements with extern references though, since that would end up with twice the number of objects. You *could* initialize the elements of the array from literals, but unfortunately you can't [use string literals as template arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033110/passing-a-string-literal-as-a-parameter-to-a-c-template-class). <s>So you'd need the proverbial layer of indirection:</s> It's painful because arrays or array references can't appear in a template parameter list (I guess this is why string literals can't):

```
// Not possible:
// const char* lits[] = { "Hello, ", "World!" };
// lit accepts const char*&, not const char*
// typedef array_<T, lit<lits[0]>, lit<lits[1]>, int_<42> > array;

// instead, but painful:
const char* hello = "Hello";
const char* world = "World!";
typedef array_<T, lit<hello>, lit<world>, int_<42> > array;
/*
 * here array::data would be an array of T, size 3,
 * initialized from { hello, world, 42 }
 */
```

I can't see how to avoid dynamic initialization without C++0x's `constexpr`, and even then there are limitations. Using some kind of tuple to build composite initializers (e.g. initialize from `{ { hello, world, 42 }, ... }`) left as an exercise. But [here's an example](http://ideone.com/knlFA).

Comment: `std::string` can't be constructed `constexpr`, since it uses dynamic allocation.

Comment: @Ben Actually since I'm using literals the problem arises when initializing from a composite of literals (please don't quote me out of context). If the element type `T` cannot be statically initialized, then obviously that can't happen, but that's unrelated (to both the question and my answer).

Comment: For posterity, `template` arguments are no longer required to have external linkage, so things in an unnamed namespace for example are OK.