# Is it possible to use std::string in a constant expression?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr, stdstring

*Using C++11, Ubuntu 14.04, GCC default toolchain*.

This code fails:

```
constexpr std::string constString = "constString";
```

> error: the type ‘const string {aka const std::basic_string}’ of
>   constexpr variable ‘constString’ is not literal... because...
>   ‘std::basic_string’ has a non-trivial destructor

Is it possible to use `std::string` in a`constexpr`? (apparently not...) If so, how? Is there an alternative way to use a character string in a `constexpr`?

Comment: `std::string` is not a literal type

Comment: @PiotrS - the question says that...

Comment: @Vector only literal types can be made `constexpr`. why do you need `std::string` to be constexpr? maybe there is alternative solution

Comment: @PiotrS. I assume that excludes user-defined or library defined literals like `std::string_literals::operator""s` that return types with non-trivial destructors

Comment: @PiotrS - yes, again, I understood the error message. Why? Why does anyone **need** a constexpr? We did just fine without it. It's an optimization. Also see: [When should you use constexpr capability in C++11?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748083/when-should-you-use-constexpr-capability-in-c11)

Comment: @Vector did I ask you what the constexpr is for or why do you want `std::string` to be constexpr? there are several compile-time string implementations on SO. what is the point in asking if you can make a non-literal type constexpr if you understand error message and know only literal types can be made constexpr? as well there are several reasons why one may want to have a constexpr instance, so I suggest you clarify your question

Comment: I agree with @PiotrS.; you already know `std::string` is impossible as `constexpr`, so obviously you *don't* need this. The next best thing is to explain what you're trying to accomplish, otherwise the default answer is to just use string literals like in my answer.

Comment: @PiotrS. - Clarified.

Comment: @tenfour - _impossible_ - the error message says _non-trivial destructor_ - I was wondering if there was a way to circumvent or implement an alternative to that destructor in a relatively safe and painless way, so it would be _trivial_. But I suppose that would mean writing my own string class...

Comment: Yes as @PiotrS. said, there are `constexpr` string implementations out there. `std::string` is not one of them.

Comment: @PiotrS - _there are several compile-time string implementations on SO_ - OK, thanks, understood. That's not an option for me but it answers my question: no way std::string will work. As I remarked to tenfour, I was wondering if there was a way to use std::string in way that would work. There are many tricks that I certainly am not aware of.

Comment: Thx. Pity indeed since we have some global const objects with empty strings. It is actual the destructor (with a 'free' call?) which prevents the constexpr to be kicked in.

Comment: `const std::string constString = "constString";`, I made it by using `const` instead of `constexpr`. And I define `const` variable in a namespace.

Comment: What exactly does it mean when some variable/object is of **literal type** and some isn't?

Answer (score 249, accepted):

No, and your compiler already gave you a comprehensive explanation.

But you could do this:

```
constexpr char constString[] = "constString";
```

At runtime, this can be used to construct a `std::string` when needed.

Comment: Why not `constexpr auto constString = "constString";`? No need to use that ugly array syntax ;-)

Comment: In the context of this question, it's clearer. My point is about which string types you can choose from. `char[]` is more verbose / clear than `auto` when I'm trying to emphasize the data type to use.

Comment: @stefan - Certainly it evaluates to what tenfour explained, but that's a very cool way to do it. :)

Comment: @tenfour Right, that's a good point. I guess I'm sometimes a bit too focused on using `auto` ;-)

Comment: I tried 'constexpr auto' in an 'template <typename T1, typename T2> constexpr' but had to change -std from c++11 to c++1y when clang said 'warning: variable declaration in a constexpr function is a C++14 extension'.

Comment: @kometen: Do you need to go as far as `std=c++1y`?  Why not just do `std=c++14`?  (Since as clang says, it's a C++14 feature)

Comment: @squidbidness That would work too I guess. This is on xcode

Comment: Would it be possible to use a `string` literal: `constexpr auto s = "c"s;`?

Comment: @FelixDombek no, but with c++17 you could use `constexpr auto s = "c"sv;` due to the introduction of `string_view`

Comment: Does it make sense to constexpr a char array in that context? If you use it to construct a string, it's going to be copied anyway. What's the difference between passing literal to the string's constructor and passing such a constexpr array to it?

Comment: Runtime construction of `std::string` this way requires memory allocation and copying, so use with care in performance-sensitive code.

Comment: @KjMag I'd just like to add that since the size of a `char[]` is known at compile time, (i.e. baked into the type for all intents and purposes), you can use some cool (and admittedly over-engineered) operations on it. I've had to write code that builds strings at compile time and verifies that character at index size is `'\0'`, before performing `&(*(char_array))` to decay back to regular char pointer, otherwise the code won't compile. The `char[]` is always created from a parameter pack of `char... c`, but not necessarily a string literal, which makes for an actual valid use case.

Comment: @stefan Because the outcome of using `auto` here is: (a) the code is less clear, (b) the code is less maintainable, (c) nothing else. AAA is evil!

Comment: @stefan usually I prefer `auto`. But there's a subtle difference: `auto` will be deduced as `const char* const`, hence `sizeof(constString)` will yield `8`. However, with the `char constString[]`-syntax, `sizeof(constString)` yields the number of characters in the string literal, which is presumably what one expects.

Comment: `std::string_view` should be preferred over char array so as to avoid implicit conversion to `std::string`. In case you already have a requirement to pass it as a `std::string` then it could be better to define it as a  `const std::string` or `static const std::string`

Answer (score 294):

As of [C++20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B20), yes, but only if the `std::string` is destroyed by the end of constant evaluation. So while your example will still not compile, something like this will:

```
constexpr std::size_t n = std::string("hello, world").size();
```

However, as of [C++17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17), you can use [`string_view`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view):

```
constexpr std::string_view sv = "hello, world";
```

A `string_view` is a [`string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)-like object that acts as an immutable, non-owning reference to any sequence of `char` objects.

Comment: Be aware that whenever you pass this constant to a function taking a `const std::string&` a new std::string has to be constructed. That is usually the opposite of what one had in mind when creating a constant. Therefore, I tend to say that this is not a good idea. At least you have to be careful.

Comment: @RamboRamon `string_view` is not implicitly convertible to `string`, so there is little danger of accidentally constructing a `string` from a `string_view`. Conversely, `char const*` _is_ implicitly convertible to `string`, so using `string_view` is actually safer in this sense.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I totally agree and indeed forgot that `string_view` is not implicitly convertible to `string`. IMO the problem I brought up is still valid but does not apply to `string_view` specifically. In fact, as you mentioned, it is even safer in that regard.

Comment: It would be great if this answer said more about what `string_view` is, instead of just a link.

Comment: Note that while a `std::string` has a `.c_str()` method, which returns a `char*` which is `NULL` terminated, `string_view` does *not*.  Like `std::string`, it has a `.data()` method which returns a `char*` which is *not* guaranteed to be null terminated (and won't be the the `string_view` is a view into another string which has no internal `NULL`s).  If you are initializing it from a compile-time constant `char` array, it *will* be `NULL` terminated, but be careful accepting `string_view` if you need to work with system calls.

Comment: @RamboRamon Easy solution: don't use `const std::string&` as a parameter! Take `std::string_view` instead when you need a string-by-reference (there are still cases where `const std::string&` might be preferred though - e.g., when working with maps and sets which can't use `std::string_view` for keys).

Comment: [Member functions of std::basic_string are constexpr: it is possible to create and use std::string objects in the evaluation of a constant expression.

However, std::string objects generally cannot be constexpr, because any dynamically allocated storage must be released in the same evaluation of constant expression.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)

Comment: @glibg10b I've edited the answer to make this clear.

Comment: cppreference says that std::string objects generally cannot be constexpr. I'm puzzled by what generally means. With MSVC I'm allowed to write `constexpr std::string s = "foobar";`

Comment: @Tohnmesiter the standard just doesn't guarantees that `std::string` objects are *constexpr*. Guarantee is the key here, compiler vendors are allowed to play with this. I mean, is not a restriction. GCC13 and Clang 16, for example, won't compile that code, since `basic_str` doesn't have a trivial destructor

Answer (score 49):

**C++20 will add `constexpr` strings and vectors**

The following proposal [has been accepted](https://herbsutter.com/2019/07/20/trip-report-summer-iso-c-standards-meeting-cologne/) apparently: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0980r0.pdf and it adds constructors such as:

```
// 20.3.2.2, construct/copy/destroy
constexpr
basic_string() noexcept(noexcept(Allocator())) : basic_string(Allocator()) { }
constexpr
explicit basic_string(const Allocator& a) noexcept;
constexpr
basic_string(const basic_string& str);
constexpr
basic_string(basic_string&& str) noexcept;
```

in addition to constexpr versions of all / most methods.

There is no support as of GCC 9.1.0, the following fails to compile:

```
#include <string>

int main() {
    constexpr std::string s("abc");
}
```

with:

```
g++-9 -std=c++2a main.cpp
```

with error:

```
error: the type ‘const string’ {aka ‘const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’} of ‘constexpr’ variable ‘s’ is not literal
```

`std::vector` discussed at: [Cannot create constexpr std::vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33241909/cannot-create-constexpr-stdvector)

Tested in Ubuntu 19.04.

Answer (score 22):

Since the problem is the non-trivial destructor so if the destructor is removed from the `std::string`, it's possible to define a `constexpr` instance of that type. Like this

```
struct constexpr_str {
    char const* str;
    std::size_t size;

    // can only construct from a char[] literal
    template <std::size_t N>
    constexpr constexpr_str(char const (&s)[N])
        : str(s)
        , size(N - 1) // not count the trailing nul
    {}
};

int main()
{
    constexpr constexpr_str s("constString");

    // its .size is a constexpr
    std::array<int, s.size> a;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is basically what c++17 `string_view` is, except that `string_view` gives you most of the functionality that you know from `std::string`

Comment: This is a bit of a nit, but I just wanted to point out that "can only construct from a char[] literal" isn't quite true. You can construct a local array, like `char test[6] { "hello" }; constexpr_str s(test);`. I just ran into this so just wanted to point that out. If you really want to enforce literals, one alternative is to pass a "const char*" as a template non-type parameter, although that's a bit finicky as well, depending on c++ version.

Answer (score 15):

C++20 is a step toward making it possible to use `std::string` at compile time, but P0980 will not allow you to write code like in your question:

```
constexpr std::string constString = "constString";
```

the reason is that `constexpr` `std::string` is allowed only to be used in `constexpr` function (constant expression evaluation context). Memory allocated by `constexpr` `std::string` must be freed before such function returns - this is the so called transient allocation, and this memory cannot 'leak' outside to runtime to `constexpr` objects (stored in data segments) accessible at runtime . For example compilation of above line of code in current VS2022 preview (cl version : 19.30.30704) results in following error:

```
1> : error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
1> : message : (sub-)object points to memory which was heap allocated during constant evaluation
```

this is because it tries to make a non-transient allocation which is not allowed - this would mean allocation into a data segment of the compiled binary.

In p0784r1, in "Non-transient allocation" paragraph, you can find that there is a plan to allow conversion of transient into static memory (emphasis mine):

> What about storage that hasn't been deallocated by the time evaluation
> completes? We could just disallow that, but there are really
> compelling use cases where this might be desirable. E.g., this could
> be the basis for a more flexible kind of "string literal" class. **We
> therefore propose that if a non-transient constexpr allocation is
> valid (to be described next), the allocated objects are promoted to
> static storage duration**.

There is a way to  export transient `std::string` data outside to make it usable at runtime. You must copy it to `std::array`, the problem is to compute the final size of `std::array`, you can either preset some large size or compute `std::string` twice - once to get size and then to get atual data. Following code successfully compiles and runs on current VS2022 preview 5. It basicly joins three words with a delimiter between words:

```
constexpr auto join_length(const std::vector<std::string>& vec, char delimiter) {
  std::size_t length = std::accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 0,
    [](std::size_t sum, const std::string& s) {
      return sum + s.size();
    });
  return length + vec.size();
}

template<size_t N>
constexpr std::array<char, N+1> join_to_array(const std::vector<std::string>& vec, char delimiter) {
  std::string result = std::accumulate(std::next(vec.begin()), vec.end(),
    vec[0],
    [&delimiter](const std::string& a, const std::string& b) {
      return a + delimiter + b;
    });
  std::array<char, N+1> arr = {};
  int i = 0;
  for (auto c : result) {
    arr[i++] = c;
  }
  return arr;
}
constexpr std::vector<std::string> getWords() {
  return { "one", "two", "three" };
}

int main()
{
  constexpr auto arr2 = join_to_array<join_length(getWords(), ';')>(getWords(), ';');
  static_assert(std::string(&arr2[0]) == "one;two;three");
  std::cout << &arr2[0] << "\n";
}
```