# Cannot create constexpr std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11

I can create `constexpr` std::array:

```
constexpr std::array<int,5> values {1,2,3,4,5};
```

It works fine. But I cannot create `constexpr` vector:

```
constexpr std::vector<int> vec = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

It gives me an error:

`the type 'const std::vector<int>' of constexpr variable 'vec' is not literal constexpr std::vector<int> vec = {1,2,3,4,5};`

Comment: Formally, that's because `vector` constructor is not declared `constexpr`. Why is it not so declared? Because `vector` constructor generally needs to allocate memory on the heap, which of course can only be done at run time.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik so, there are no way to create constexpr vector?

Comment: No there is not. Why would you want to? It makes little sense to me. The whole point of `vector` is its ability to resize dynamically. If you don't need that, just use `std::array` or plain array.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik. Actually, I am using `Qt` and there are nothing like `std::array` container, so I tried to use `QVector` and `QList` and it does not work. I don't want to mix `Qt` and `stl` containers.  So, I guess now I have to

Comment: There are use cases, for example if you have a global array of pair<enum, vector> where vector can consist of a limited (but variable) numbers known at compile time.

Comment: @Leo `QVarLengthArray` same as std::array https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qvarlengtharray.html

Answer (score 25, accepted):

AFAIK The `initlializer_list` constructor of `std::vector<>` is not declared `constexpr`.

Comment: Actually, it is declared constexpr: c++20 draft: https://wg21.link/std20#lstlisting.22.-2632   and still in current draft sources: https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/6091e264374349c12aa775cd66e5f062d9c7b9e4/source/containers.tex#L5706    it seems, it's just not yet implemented...

Comment: It seems, the only compiler, that currently supports it is Visual Studio: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support#:~:text=constexpr%20std%3A%3Avector

Answer (score 86):

There is a proposal to make `std::vector` `constexpr`: https://github.com/ldionne/wg21/blob/master/generated/p1004r1.pdf There is a whole talk about the upcoming `C++20/23` changes: https://youtu.be/CRDNPwXDVp0?t=3080 So check again with `C++20`!

[edit]: `constexpr std::vector` has been approved for `C++20`! https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/au0c4x/201902_kona_iso_c_committee_trip_report_c20/

[edit 2019-10]: gcc trunk (with `--std=c++2a` flag) has started to implement `constexpr new` (a prerequisite for `constexpr vector`). See: https://youtu.be/FRTmkDiW5MM?t=372

[edit 2021-11]: **both `constexpr std::vector` and `constexpr std::basic_string` are now implemented in `gcc 12`** ( https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support )

Comment: It has gone into C++20, together with `std::string`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57284740/895245

Comment: both `constexpr std::vector` and `constexpr std::basic_string` are implemented in GCC 12 (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support)

Comment: Thanks @DesmondGold. I added this to the original answer. Much appreciated!

Comment: But constexpr vector doesn't mean that the OP's code has become valid, it is still rejected.

Comment: OP's code remains invalid because the `constexpr std::vector` is in use **at runtime**. No problem otherwise if `vec` is declared in a `constexpr` function. (Or, use `constexpr std::array`.)

Comment: The only remaining question is: Why?

Answer (score 36):

For c++ version at least prior C++2a:

`std::vector` uses a dynamic memory allocation. Operator `new` can't be used in `constexpr` methods, thus `std::vector` will never be `constexpr`, constexpr constructor can't be declared for it.
`std::array` doesn't use dynamic memory allocation, it is allocated in stack. It has no any problem with rules of creation constexpr objects and can be constexpr.