# Why is std::vector::push_back declared as constexpr in C++20?

Tags: c++, stdvector, c++20, constexpr

According to [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back), in C++20, `std::vector::push_back` is declared as follows:

```
constexpr void push_back(const T& value);
```

I cannot imagine a scenario in which `push_back` should be `constexpr`.

**What's the rationale behind?**

Comment: Maybe has to do with making the `constexpr std::vector` as a whole(?). Check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52801072/14624729).

Comment: Any inconvenience  if `resize` is not `constexpr`?

Comment: You wouldn't be able to use resize in a constant context.

Comment: Can `resize`, or even `push_back`, be used in a constant context? @eerorika

Comment: @xmllmx In C++20, yes: https://godbolt.org/z/KKb8dPo44 (only MSVC seems to have implemented constexpr vector so far).

Comment: Mutable functions has been done `constexpr` to allow their usage in constexpr functions. C++20 now allows `std::vector` usage in constexpr functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any rationale behind?

This is the abstract of the proposal. There is no separate rationale section:

> P1004R2 Making std::vector constexpr
>
> Abstract
>
> std::vector is not currently constexpr friendly. With the loosening of requirements on constexpr in [P0784R1] and related papers, we can now make std::vector constexpr, and **we should in order to support the constexpr reflection effort (and other evident use cases)**.

Answer (score 3):

In general all deterministic operations (so no `rand()`) should be `constexpr`, because why not? You can use the same code for runtime as well as for compile time computation, which is great, because you reduce the repetition and your constexpr code is more idiomatic. In case of the `constexpr` use case the memory allocation and `push_back` function are invoked in compiler virtual machine, which emulate your runtime machine