# c++20 seems to be not supporting constexpr vector - is my installation incorrect

Tags: c++, c++20, constexpr

I just finished upgrading my compiler to C++20 on ubuntu 20.04. `g++ version` gives me the following output :

```
c++ (Ubuntu 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) 10.3.0
```

I am trying the following code as suggested on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69498115/c20-constexpr-vector-and-string-not-working#:%7E:text=constexpr%20allocation%20support%20in%20C,the%20end%20of%20constant%20evaluation.&text=v%20can%27t%20be%20constant,not%20allowed%20to%20do%20so.)

```
constexpr int f() {
    std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3};
    return v.size();
}

int main() {
    static_assert(f() == 3);
}
```

But I am getting the following error :

```
error: variable ‘v’ of non-literal type ‘std::vector<int>’ in ‘constexpr’ function
```

Am I going wrong somewhere. Or is my installation incorrect

Comment: You probably didn't enable 20 standard support. Put -std=c++20 to your compiler options list

Comment: I am already compiling using `-std=c++20`. The problem is still there. Some other features like `cobsteval` and `constinit` are working fine though

Comment: I've tried your code in [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/) with gcc compiler, it produces the same error up to version 11.3 (including 10.3), but works fine starting from 12.1

Comment: I don't know how you upgraded your compiler, but it's not close to the latest version. C++20 is not yet fully implemented by all compilers, even in the latest version. That a compiler has a C++20 flag doesn't guarantee that. Only MSVC say they have every C++20 feature, but that doesn't guarantee you can't run into a bug .

Comment: I found that ubuntu 20.04 does not support gcc 12.1 and hence not all features are supported

Comment: @user3282758 that's nonsense. You can always [install from source](https://tutorialforlinux.com/2022/05/25/step-by-step-gcc-12-1-ubuntu-20-04-installation-guide/)

Comment: Of course building from source would work. The update gave me what I mentioned earlier. Not everyone is as informed as you might be. Some may need support and time

Comment: Dupe: [both `constexpr std::vector` and `constexpr std::basic_string` are now implemented in gcc 12](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52801072/12002570)

Comment: Don't take my comments as intended shaming or such. I think there is a clash of cultures here. I'm just trying to inform you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to upgrade `gcc` to at least 12 to get the C++23 `constexpr` support for non-literal types as `std::vector<int>`.

From [compiler support @ cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support):

|  |  | gcc | clang | EDG eccp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Non-literal variables (and labels and `goto`s) in `constexpr` functions | [P2242R3](https://wg21.link/P2242R3) | 12 | 15 | 6.3 |

Feature test:

```
__cpp_constexpr >= 202110L
```

Comment: Dupe: [both `constexpr std::vector` and `constexpr std::basic_string` are now implemented in gcc 12](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52801072/12002570)