# How to explicitly call the specified overload function?

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-warnings

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
constexpr char str[] = "/home/qspace/etc/client/mmkvcfgsvr_test_byset_cli.conf";

void test(bool a)
{
    printf("b=%d",a);
}

void test(const std::string& s){
    printf("s=%s",s.c_str());
}
int main()
{
  test(str);
  return 0;
}
```

Like this code, the C++ compiler will convert char* to bool and then call the first function, which is inconsistent with my original intention.
Is there any way to prevent the compiler from performing type conversions that I don't want?
Like "-fno-permissive", but unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try explicitly constructing a `std::string{str}`?

Comment: C doesn't have function overloading

Comment: You just need to set the correct argument type, instead of `std::string &`, use `char *`

Comment: Do not tag C for C++ questions.

Comment: @fedemengo: Defining a `test` as `void test(char * s)` does not result it in being called over the `void test(bool a)`, as tested in Apple Clang 11.0.0. Making it `void test(const char *s)` does.

Comment: To clarify your question, there are ways to define a `test` that will be called in preference to `void test(bool a)`, such as `void test(const char *s)`, and there are ways to change the argument so that `void test(const std::string &s)` is called rather than `void test(bool a)`, but are you specifically asking not for those but for a way to suppress the conversion to bool given the two function definitions as shown?

Comment: @EricPostpischil right, replacing `std:: string &` with `char *`  will result in `const char * s` which is what I meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to explicitly call the specified overload function?

- Convert the argument at call site: `test(std::string(str));`
- Take expected address of overload function: `static_cast<void(*)(const std::string&)>(print)(str);`

> Is there any way to prevent the compiler from performing type conversions that I don't want?

You might add a catch-all overload as deleted: `template <typename T> void test(const T&) = delete;`

Alternatively, in C++17, you might do the "dispatching" manually:

```
template <typename T>
void test(const T& t)
{
    static_assert(std::is_constructible_v<std::string, T>
               || std::is_convertible_v<T, bool>);

    if constexpr (std::is_constructible_v<std::string, T>) {
        const std::string& s = t;
        printf("s=%s", s.c_str());
    } else if constexpr (std::is_convertible_v<T, bool>) {
        printf("b=%d", bool(t));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing C and STL types (char array vs std::string). There are two solutions. The immediately obvious solution is to create a temporary std::string object every time you wish to pass a char array into a function expecting std::string.

```
test(std::string(str));
```

The other solution, which I prefer, is to avoid C types altogether. To create a string constant, use STL type directly:

```
const std::string str {"/home/qspace/etc/client/mmkvcfgsvr_test_byset_cli.conf"};
```

If you wish to retain `constexpr` see this thread: [Is it possible to use std::string in a constexpr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27123306/is-it-possible-to-use-stdstring-in-a-constexpr)