# Why can't I declare a string constexpr in MSVC?

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, c++20, constexpr

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27123306/is-it-possible-to-use-stdstring-in-a-constexpr) and other sources, most constructors for `std::string` are `constexpr` as of C++20.

Below, I attempt to use constructor (5) from [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    constexpr std::string example{ "word" };
    std::cout << example;
}
```

I ran this in Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.11.4 with both /std:c++20 and /std:c++lastest enabled.

Both give the error

```
error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
message : failure was caused by allocated storage not being deallocated
```

According to row "constexpr std::string" in [this table](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support), the feature should be present.

Am I doing something wrong? Has this feature been implemented?

Comment: Unfortunately the most-upvoted answers on that question were written years before C++20 was actually finalized, and it turns out that the utility of `std::string`'s `constexpr` constructors is somewhat narrower than predicted. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69590837/12334309) has more details about the circumstances in which you can and cannot make use of the `constexpr` constructors.

Comment: Thanks! I'll add for future readers that this also applies to ```constexpr std::vector```.

Comment: Yes, anything that has to make heap allocations can only do so transiently.