# How to generate field name of a class knowing its type?

Tags: c++

Here is a sample code to clarify what I want to achieve:

```
template<typename T>
struct Compose{
    T some_way_to_make_name_out_of_type(T);
// -------------------^
// It may be some preprocessor hack or something based on templates
};
```

The reason I want to do this is that there is a way to check if the field of a certain type exists in the class. So I want to unify the names.

The only limitations are

- the name must be **unique with respect to type**.
- It is preferred not to use external code generation tools like [Cog](https://nedbatchelder.com/code/cog/) (Boost is OK though)

My goal is to make the way to generalize approach from the code above and make the same `Compose` structure, but for any number of types:

```
template <typename ... ComponentsTypes>
struct Compose {
//....
};


using Compose<int, float, std::string> = ifsType;

ifsType ifs{};

ifs.int_field = 3;
ifs.float_field = 4.0;
ifs.std_string_filed = "hi";
```

Let's assume that it is never desired to compose two components of the same type.

```
using Compose<int, int> = iiType; // <-- will not compile
```

Comment: How about using `std::tuple`, and use something like `ifs.get<int>() = 3;` or `get<int>(ifs.data) = 3;`? detecting if tuple contains type is as easy than detecting member.

Comment: Looks like you want `std::tuple`

Comment: If you really want member names based on templates, it is not possible. Someone suggested a way to achieve it using the preprocessor here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33099226/c-generic-template-method-name-from-template-parameter

Comment: Hmm, maybe I want tuples. @Jarod42, though I heard that they are not very nice to use. If no better way will come up I think your comment is close to answering to my question.

Comment: @MihailFeraru, variadic macroses are a good idea actually.

Comment: "Nice to use" is a very use case specific thing. Depends on what are you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot generate member name from template parameter.
You can play with MACRO, something like:

```
#define DEFINE_COMPOSE(type) \
  struct Compose_ ## type { \
      T T ## _field; \
  }

DEFINE_COMPOSE(int);

Compose_int ifs;
ifs.int_field = 3;
```

Variadic Macro can be used to handle up-to some hard count limit.

In regular C++, `std::tuple` seems enough:

```
template <typename ... Ts>
struct Compose
{
    std::tuple<Ts...> data;

    template <typename T>
    T& get() { return std::get<T>(data); }

    template <typename T>
    const T& get() const { return std::get<T>(data); }

    // Code to detect if T is in Ts...
    template <typename T>
    static constexpr bool has_type() { return (std::is_same_v<T, Ts> || ...); }
};

// With possible usage:
void foo()
{
    Compose<int, float, std::string> ifs;
    
    ifs.get<int>() = 3;
    std::get<int>(ifs.data) = 3;

    static_assert(Compose<int, float, std::string>::has_type<float>());
    static_assert(!Compose<int, float, std::string>::has_type<char>());
}
```