# Array as non-type template argument

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

I noticed that

```
template <size_t n, char[n]> class x
{
};
```

is happily accepted by my C++ compiler. However, when I naively attempt something like

```
x <4, "hey"> something;
```

I get a nice

```
Non type template argument does not refer to any declaration
```

So I wonder: how would I go with actually making a class out of that template?

Comment: My guess would be that your compiler is seeing the string literal of "hey" as a const char* not a char[]

Comment: What if you say `x<5, "hey"> something;`, I don't think the compiler is going to enforce the type safety here.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>

template <size_t n, char s[n]>
class X {
public:
  X() {
    std::cout << s;
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
};

char hey[] = "hey";

int main() {
  X<4, hey> x;
}
```

But `X<4, "hey"> x;` does not compile because, for a non-type template argument, certain restrictions apply:

> For pointers to objects, the template arguments have to designate the
>   address of an object with static storage duration and a linkage
>   (either internal or external), or a constant expression that evaluates
>   to the appropriate null pointer or std::nullptr_t value.

This raises another issue, I found the following on cppreference.com:

> Array and function types may be written in a template declaration, but
>   they are automatically replaced by pointer to object and pointer to
>   function as appropriate.

So `s` is actually a pointer, therefore the following will compile:

```
X<5, hey> something;
```

Potential buffer-overflow problem.

Comment: I am not getting what the difference is between `X<"hey">` and `char hey[] = "hey"; X<hey>`. Is there any way to use a more compact notation, something similar to the `"hey"` version?

Comment: In short, string literals do not have linkage, they don't even have names.

Comment: It's not supported in the current standard. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033110/passing-a-string-literal-as-a-parameter-to-a-c-template-class

Answer (score 0):

```
template <size_t n, char[n]> class x
{
};

char foobar[]="hey";

x<4, foobar> y;
```

Compiles with gcc 5.3.1

Comment: I'd guess that argument needs to have linkage.