# Declare std::array member variable's size based on constructor string literal

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr

I need a class which takes in a compile-time string literal (const char* const) as its only constructor argument.

I would like to have an std::array member variable store the words in this string literal (split up using spaces, for example). The size of this array therefore will never change, as the string literal is known at compile-time.

How can I have this array as a member variable, while having its size be specified by the number of words passed in to the constructor?

I would like to make it so that the caller does not need to specify the number of words in the class template parameters, but that the constructor (presumably a constexpr one) could deduce this at compile time.

I do not want to use a vector, as it is unnecessary for this situation (the words being stored will NEVER change). How would I go about this?

Thanks

Comment: You need to show what you've done so far and where you're getting an error.

Comment: I have not done much as I do not know where to start... I have just been Googling but to no avail.

Comment: You can't do this.  If you don't know the size at class definition time, then you have to use a vector or make the class itself a template that you pass the size to.

Comment: @NathanOliver could I not somehow have a constexpr function which gets "called" with the string literal as an argument an deduces the number of words, and then passes that along to std::array?

Comment: gcc/clang has extension to have string literal in UDL using template (so having char_sequence which allows to know word count at compile time).

Comment: Not if you want to pass this string into the constructor.  In order to define the class itself, like `struct foo { std::array<char, some_size> };` you have to know that `some_size` right then.  You can't change the size of the class in the constructor so there is no way of passing it to the constructor.

Comment: if you want something like that, you definitely have to go with the `make_xyz` idiom. Also have a look at `boost::hana::string` https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/libs/hana/doc/html/structboost_1_1hana_1_1string.html

Comment: String literals are not `const char*`s; they're `const char[N]`s.

Comment: Related: [Passing a string literal as a parameter to a C++ template class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033110/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to use class templates, as there should be a different size of the class for different string literals. Template arguments should at least contain the size of the enclosed array (e.g. `template<std::size_t N>`).

Then you may find Class Template Argument Deduction from C++17 useful so you don't have to specify size automatically. You can either use automatic deduction from constructor or provide custom deduction guides. If you don't have C++17, you can create a helper function similar to `make_pair`/`make_tuple` which will employ template argument deduction and create the corresponding class.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

template<std::size_t N>
struct WordStorage {
    std::array<char, N> char_array;
    WordStorage(const char (&char_array_)[N]) {
        std::copy(char_array_, char_array_ + N, char_array.begin());
    }
};

int main() {
    WordStorage s("hello");  // Deduced to WordStorage<6> as "hello" is const char[6].
    static_assert(s.char_array.size() == 6);
    std::cout << s.char_array.data() << "\n";
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the answer I was looking for for the most part - thank you so much. Just a question - how would I "provide custom deduction guides"? I quick Google search didn't really help much. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: See [code examples here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction#User-defined_deduction_guides)

Answer (score 0):

probably closest thing you can get in my opinion :

---

```
template <char... c>
class foo
{
private:
    std::array<char, sizeof...(c)> m_arr;

public:
    foo()
    {
        std::cout << m_arr.size()<<'\n'; //ok : prints 3
    }
};

int main()
{
    foo<'c', 'h', 'a'> f;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is highly unpractical for my use case :( unless maybe there's any easy way to make a macro that will have the same effect? I also ultimately need to process the incoming string somehow and make the array based on the number of words so this specific method isn't enough in that regard either.... hmm.

Comment: @yeputons' answer with template argument deduction seems to work