# Add the instance name to the constructor arguments as an std::string with Macros

Tags: c++, macros

More precisely, I have a class:

```
struct S 
{
    template <class... T>
    S(std::string instance_name, T*... ptrs);
}
```

That needs to be constructed in a way like:

```
STRUCT(example(arg1, arg2, arg3));
```

Where `STRUCT` is the macro that expands to:

```
S example(std::string("example"), arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

I have been trying with `#define X(a) #a` but can't figure out how to make it all work.

Thanks

EDIT:

I have a map filled with pairs of `<std::string, void*>` where functions pointers are stored. Those functions stored there have a counterpart function with the signature: `example(Args args)`, where both functions have same arguments.
So I have entries in the map such as ("example", &example_counterpart) and I want the user to be able to call example_counterpart(...) with something like: `OTHER(example(Args args));`

The solution you gave is quite close, but the function is called (in the constructor of `S`) with `MACRO(example, arg1, arg2)`, which is not exactly what I need.

I m open to other suggestions to achieve this, the use of the class is just an idea I had but its not important, the things I cant change is the fact I have those counterpart functions stored in a map and I need to call them with some sort of flag to differentiate it from the normal function call.

I hope my intent it's clear, even tho the reasons might not

Comment: Is `STRUCT(example, (arg1, arg2, arg3))` or `STRUCT(example, arg1, arg2, arg3)` acceptable?

Comment: Sadly not, because I would need to replicate a function call, such as example(arg1, arg2, arg3);

Comment: `STRUCT(example)(arg1, arg2, arg3)` perhaps? It would still involve higher-level indirection tricks, including creation of a class that has an `operator()(T*...)` to forward the extra arguments.

Comment: @MSalters Well that would be the best solution so far

Comment: The updated question really makes me wonder about the quality of the underlying design. Storing function pointers in `void*` ? IIRC, it's implementation-defined whether that is even possible. The 21st century solution would be `std::function<Result(Args)>`

Comment: @MSalters The functions I' m talking about are CUDA kernels and cannot be stored in the way you mentioned, I also feel like this is getting unhelpfully out of topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestion:

```
#define STRUCT(inst,...) S inst(std::string(#inst),__VA_ARGS__)
```

It would then be used slightly different from what you want:

```
STRUCT(example, arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

... but it expands to exactly what you want:

```
S example(std::string("example"), arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xee1v9E74)

Comment: There is no tool with macros to distinguish the "example" from the parameters? I was hoping with some workaround to be able to accomplish it

Comment: @AathakA: `STRUCT(example(arg1, arg2, arg3))` is a macro **with one argument**. You can expand that one argument one time, or two, but each time you expand the macro argument the whole macro argument `example(arg1, arg2, arg3)` will be expanded.

Comment: @AathakA Not that I know of but leave the question open for a few hours and perhaps someone with magic macro skills comes along and is able to solve that.

Comment: @MSalters I updated the question, in the hope there are solutions

Answer (score 0):

`STRUCT(example(arg1, arg2, arg3))` will expand macro `#define STRUCT(a) ...` with `a=example(arg1, arg2, arg3)`. Hence, `#a` will be `"example(arg1, arg2, arg3)"`.

You're going to need to a type for `example`, and that type will need to capture `#a`. I.e. `Helper<S, #a>` with `Helper<S, const char* name>` a template class derived from `S`. Slight catch: [you can't pass that string literal directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033110/passing-a-string-literal-as-a-type-argument-to-a-class-template), you'll need to capture it in a helper variable.

In `Helper<S, name>` you'll need to (constexpr) parse `name`, and the initializer list of `Helper<S>::Helper(T*...args)` will need to pass both that parsed name and `args...` down to `S::S`.