# What does ::template mean?

Tags: c++, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Since yesterday, I see C++11 code that use something like `ComplexTypeOrTypedef::template`, for example from the last 2 hours, from two unrelated sources I saw it:

- http://accu.org/index.php/journals/c310/ (Overload 109 PDF - p21 - Listing 4)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/7420711/951426

Google doesn't help me (it doesn't seem to care about the colons in my search: ``::template c++11`), the StackOverflow search neither, it's quite depressing!

What does this mysterious `::template` things mean?

Comment: See this FAQ: [What is the `->template`, `.template` and `::template` syntax about?](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/techtalk/templates/#templateprefix).

Comment: Also note this is not new to C++11. It applies just as much to C++03.

Comment: Thanks you all for the pointer and sorry for the duplicate. I don't fully understand the syntax for now (when and how should I use it) but I will re-read the Johannes Schaub - litb answer.