# Template argument string vs. int

Tags: c++, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Strings as template arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826464/strings-as-template-arguments)

Why the first declaration is OK but the second is not? Why `std::string` is not suitable?

```
template <typename T, T x> struct foo { };

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    foo<int, 0> f_int;              // ok
    foo<string, ""> f_string;      // not ok
}
```

I get:

```
error: a non-type template parameter cannot have type 'std::basic_string<char>'
```

using clang++.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You simply cannot have a template parameter of type `std::string`. The rules for non-type template parameters are defined by the standard as follows (§14.1/4):

> A non-type *template-parameter* shall have one of the following (optionally *cv-qualified*) types:
>
> - integral or enumeration type,
> - pointer to object or pointer to function,
> - lvalue reference to object or lvalue reference to function,
> - pointer to member,
> - `std::nullptr_t`.

In addition (§14.1/7):

> A non-type *template-parameter* shall not be declared to have floating point, class, or void type.

As `std::string` is a class type, your instantiation of `foo` is not allowed.

Answer (score 5):

Because a non-type template parameter (ugly name for "value") should be computable at compile time and `std::string` is not (it may require dynamic memory allocation thus its constructor is not `constexpr`).