# Some trouble passing a "const char" parameter in templates even in Visual C++ Compiler Nov 2013 CTP

Tags: c++, templates, parameter-passing

Hi and happy new year to everyone,

I have some troubles passing passing a "const char" parameter in templates even in the last versión Compiler Nov 2013 CTP of Visual C++! This is the simple code that doesn't work in the latest Visual C++ compiler but yes with "g++" with the option "std=c++x0",

```
#include <stdlib.h>


template<char _parameterChar>
class A
{
    char varChar;
public:
    A(){ varChar = _parameterChar; }
    ~A(){}
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const char a_1 = 'a';
    const char a_2 = "abcdef"[0]; // This instruction gets a constant 'a'.


    A<'a'> first_A; // compile ok!
    A<a_1> second_A; // compile ok!
    A<a_2> third_A; // --->  This not compiles!! Why not ?!?!?!

    return 0;
}
```

Visual C++ compiler gives that error,

```
error C2971: 'A' : template parameter '_parameterChar' : 'a_2' : a local variable cannot be used as a non-type argument
```

I think that is a restricción of compiler, because "abcdef"[0], you could get the const char 'a' at compile time, isn't it ?

Comment: @hetepeperfan: As far as I can see, it's a constant expression, so can be used as a template argument. What exactly do you think disqualifies it from being a constant expression?

Comment: This code does compile just fine with `g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9) 4.8.1`. Might the problem be that the value of `"abcdef"[0]` is not deduced at compile time in the compiler you use?

Comment: For what it's worth, Clang also rejects this. But I'm struggling to see what disqualifies `"abcdef"[0]` from being a constant expression, so I can't say which compiler is correct.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I think it might be legal in C++11, but it certainly wasn't in pre-C++11.  (And it wouldn't surprise me if g++ supported this as an extension, even in pre-C++11.)

Comment: It's strange that `const char a_2 = "abcde"[0];` is legal but rejected in the template argument.

Comment: @hetepeperfan: Template arguments are stricter than variable initalisers, since they must be known at compile time. So it's not surprising that some expressions can be used as an initialiser, but not a template argument.

Comment: @hetepeperfan Why would that be strange? You can initialize a const variable with a value of a non constant expression, can't you?

Comment: What you are telling me is that If compilers with C++0x have diferent behaviours then some compilers doesn't follow the standards. isn't it? 
Or maybe is a improvement in the future.
Too many thanks for your quick responses! I'm glad to know this site it is very alive :)

Comment: @JordiEspada What we're saying is clear: in C++0x, this is clearly not legal.  (Integral constant expressions cannot involve pointers.)  In C++11, it's not 100% clear, but probably is legal. But not all compilers support C++11; in particular, according to Microsoft, Visual C++ 2013 does _not_ support extended const expressions.  (The fact that this depends on a new feature of C++11 explains why different compilers handle it differently.  Different compilers implement different subsets of the new features.)

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that the standard says that `"abcdef"[0]` is not a constant expression.  Logically, the compiler could probably work it out, but the standard doesn't list it in the allowed operations.  Evaluation of the expression involves an lvalue to rvalue conversion, and only a very limited number of lvalue to rvalue conversions are allowed.  (Actually, it may be legal in C++11.  But if this is the case, it would be a new feature, and possibly not implemented by your compiler.)

Comment: As I said, I use the latest compiler Nov 2013 CTP. I don't know if I have to configure specific build options. Despite that the C++ standard says, I think that is a right const value rvalue for me.

Comment: @JordiEspada It definitely isn't in older C++.  It may seem const to a human reader, but it's less than obvious to a compiler, given the way a compiler works.

Comment: @JordiEspada With regards to the compiler, there are a lot of C++11 features which aren't yet supported by Visual C++.  (The same can be said of most compilers.)  This looks like it would be covered by the "constexpr" entry in the table at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx; in other words, it is _not_ yet supported, even in the most recent release of Visual Studios.

Answer (score 1):

James Kanze says the "abcdef"[0] is not a constant expression, but I think it is from standard.

standard 5.19.3

> An integral constant expression is an expression of integral or
>   unscoped enumeration type, **implicitly converted to a prvalue**, where
>   the converted expression is a core constant expression.

standard 5.19.2

> an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (is not a core constant expression) unless it is applied to:
>
> a non-volatile glvalue of integral or enumeration type that refers to
>   a non-volatile const object with a preceding initialization,
>   initialized with a constant expression **[ Note: a string literal
>   (2.14.5) corresponds to an array of such objects. —end note ]**,

Comment: Then what you say is than a string literal is initialized through constant chars, isn't it ?

Comment: Not exactly, what I say is string literal is an array of const objects, therefore each element in this array shall be a const object, i.e., "abcdef"[0] shall be a const object.

Comment: @user534498 I didn't say it wasn't; I said I wasn't sure (in C++11---in pre-C++11, it clearly isn't).  I'm currently tending to saying it is, but I'm not 100% sure.  But even if it is in C++11, this is a significant change with regards to earlier versions, and it is quite possible that a compiler doesn't support it yet.  (None of the compilers I have access to fully support C++11.  Although all have support for some features, they're not always the features you most want.)

Answer (score 1):

Currently this code compiles and works as expected on Visual Studio 2017 (Windows). No need to do a specific configuration settings, just enough default console application. Unfortunately I haven't ability to check it on previous versions of VS.

Comment: You are right Pavel K. I had to wait a newer version of MSVC++ :)