# Template static class with string list as template parameter, how to make on c++ 11

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

It's hard to explain clearly, so sorry for unclear title. I need template class, that takes list of strings (char* ?) as template parameter. This class must have static method `static string get(int i);`, that will return nth string from passed as template static list of string. How can it be coded?

Goal is to make child classes with assigned list of strings. Something like this:

```
class Letters : public Base<"A", "B", "C"> {};
...
std::cout << Letters::get(1);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826464/c-style-strings-as-template-arguments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Dragos Pop mentioned in the comments, [it is impossible to use a *string literal* as a template argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826464/c-style-strings-as-template-arguments).

Possible workarounds:

- If you only need *letters*, consider using `char`:

  ```
  Base<'A', 'B', 'C'>
  ```
- Consider passing *callable object types* instead of *string literals*. The callable objects will return the string literals you require.

  ```
  struct String0
  {
      constexpr auto operator()() const noexcept
      {
          return "some string 0";   
      }
  };

  struct String1
  {
      constexpr auto operator()() const noexcept
      {
          return "some string 1";   
      }
  };

  class Words : public Base<String0, String1> { /* ... */ };
  ```

Comment: Thanks! Thinking it is "true way"

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `C++11`, you can get the same behavior easily using `std::tuple`, here is the code

```
typedef std::tuple<string, string, string> mytpl;

mytpl tpl = make_tuple("A", "B", "C");

cout << get<0>(tpl).c_str() << endl;
cout << get<1>(tpl).c_str() << endl;
cout << get<2>(tpl).c_str() << endl;
```