# constexpr parametrized function pointer

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17, constexpr

I have the following third-party API:

```cpp
using StatisticsFunc = double (*)(const std::vector<double> &)
libraryClass::ComputeStatistics(StatisticsFunc sf);
```

Which I'm using like this:

```cpp
obj1->ComputeStatistics([](const auto& v) {return histogram("obj1", v);};
obj2->ComputeStatistics([](const auto& v) {return histogram("obj2", v);};
```

But all those lambdas are just repeated code. I'd rather have it like this:

```cpp
obj1->ComputeStatistics(getHistogramLambda("obj1"));
```

So I need to define:

```cpp
constexpr auto getHistogramLambda(const char* name) {
    return [](const auto& v) {return histogram(name, v);};
}
```

But it won't work, because `name` is not captured. Neither will this work:

```cpp
constexpr auto getHistogramLambda(const char* name) {
    return [name](const auto& v) {return histogram(name, v);};
}
```

Because capturing lambda is not stateless anymore and cannot be cast to function pointer.

Ofc one can do it as a macro, but I want a modern C++ 17 solution.

Passing string as template argument seems an option as well:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28209546/7432927 , but I'm curious if there's a `constexpr` way of doing it.

Comment: If you're not capturing the string by value, then what is meant to stop a user from passing a string that *isn't* a literal, one whose lifetime may end before the callback gets called?

Comment: Could you possibly change `StatisticsFunc` to `std::function<double(const std::vector<double>&)>`?

Comment: Template seems like the way to go, I doubt that it is doable with some constexpr cleverness.

Comment: @aschepler this is a part of the third party API, I cannot change it.

Comment: @NicolBolas well, the string is passed to `constexpr` function, so I'd like to enforce it being known at compile time.

Comment: @PrzemysławCzechowski: `constexpr` functions do not *have* to be executed at compile-time.

Comment: Are you really taking a pointer to a pointer to a function? I feel like there's an extra `*` - I went ahead and removed it

Comment: Are there any reason for using lambas.  What about old school i.e. something like  obj1->ComputeStatistics([std::bind](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)(histogram,"obj1",_1))

Comment: @VictorGubin Need to end up with a function pointer, so that won't work.

Comment: Also an option, extend the libraryClass and add a field object_name_ and generic method like - `double HistogramStatistics() { return ComputeStatistics([object_name_](const auto& v) {return histogram(object_name_, v); }`. Or create a facade class like HistorgramStatisic which took object and it's name as a constructor parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort of.

This:

```
obj1->ComputeStatistics(getHistogramLambda("obj1"));
```

Won't work for the reasons you point out - you need to capture state. And then, we can't write this:

```
obj1->ComputeStatistics(getHistogramLambda<"obj1">());
```

Because while we can have template parameters of type `const char*` we can't have them bind to string literals. You *could* do it this way:

```
template <const char* name>
constexpr auto getHistogramLambda() {
    return [](const auto& v) {return histogram(name, v);};
}

const char p[] = "obj1";
obj1->ComputeStatistics(getHistogramLambda<p>());
```

Which is pretty awkward because you need to introduce the extra variable for each invocation. In C++20, we'll be able to write a class type that has as its template paramater a fixed string, which will allow `getHistogramLambda<"obj1">` to work, just in a slightly different way.

Until then, the best way currently is probably to use a UDL to capture the individual characters as template parameters of some class type:

```
template <char... Cs>
constexpr auto getHistogramLambda(X<Cs...>) {
    static constexpr char name[] = {Cs..., '\0'};
    return [](const auto& v) { return histogram(name, v);};
}


obj->ComputeStatistic(getHistogramLambda("obj1"_udl));
```

The intent here is that `"obj"_udl` is an object of type `X<'o', 'b', 'j', '1'>` - and then we reconstruct the string within the body of the function template in a way that still does not require capture.

Is this worth it to avoid the duplication? Maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Different answer, courtesy of [Michael Park](https://mpark.github.io/programming/2017/05/26/constexpr-function-parameters/). We can encode the value we want in a type - not passing the string literal we want as a function argument or a template argument, but as an actual type - and that way we don't need to capture it:

```
#define CONSTANT(...) \
  union { static constexpr auto value() { return __VA_ARGS__; } }
#define CONSTANT_VALUE(...) \
  [] { using R = CONSTANT(__VA_ARGS__); return R{}; }()


template <typename X>
constexpr auto getHistogramLambda(X) {
    return [](const auto& v) { return histogram(X::value(), v);};
}

obj->ComputeStatistic(getHistogramLambda(CONSTANT_VALUE("obj1")));
obj->ComputeStatistic(getHistogramLambda(CONSTANT_VALUE("obj2")));
```

Not sure this is better than the UDL approach in this particular case, but it's an interesting technique for sure.

Comment: well, if we allow using macros, we can as well do:
`#define HISTOGRAM_LAMBDA(X)  [] (const auto& v) { return histogram(X, v);};`
the idea of the question is to acheive it without macros, in some "modern" `constexpr` way. But thanks for your contribution.

Comment: @PrzemysławCzechowski Those... aren't equivalent. This is a general solution for encasing a value in a type, that is a very specific solution to this problem that just saves you a little bit of typing.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure to understand what do you exactly need but... what about declaring a global `constexpr` array of `char const` pointers

```
constexpr std::array<char const *, 3u> arrStr {{"obj0", "obj1", "obj2"}};
```

then receiving in `getHistogramLambda()` the index of the required string as template parameter?

```
template <std::size_t N>
constexpr auto getHistogramLambda () {
    return [](const auto& v) {return histogram(arrStr.at(N), v);};
}
```

This way you can call `ComputeStatistic()` as follows

```
obj1->ComputeStatistics(getHistogramLambda<1u>());
```